# How to fix the issue while installing pytext via pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pytext

While trying to install pytext-nlp through pip, I'm getting the following error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.0.1.post2 (from pytext-nlp) (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.0.1.post2 (from pytext-nlp)
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Not enough info - what OS are you on, what is the output of `python --version`, `pip --version`? If you are on windows, or using 32bit Python, or using Python 3.4 or older, than you won't be able to install `torch` from PyPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[torch version 1.0.1.post2](https://pypi.org/project/torch/1.0.1.post2/#files) is available for Python 2.7 and 3.5-3.7, Linux and MacOS, only 64 bit.

If you have a different OS (w32, for example), a different version of Python (like 3.5) or 32-bit Python you cannot install the package.